# RxJS Chained ShareReplay doesn't multicast properly

Tags: angular, rxjs6

When composing Observables ShareReplay is not working as expected. The following is a simple example.

```
apiData = this.api.get(url).pipe(
  tap(() => console.log('Data Fetched')),
  shareReplay(1)
);

work = this.apiData.pipe(
  tap(() => console.log('Building Controls')),
  tap((data) => this.buildControls(data)),
  shareReplay(1)
);

dataBasedOncontrols = this.work.pipe(
  tap(() => console.log('Computed Data')),
  switchMap(() => this.controlDataStream())
);
```

In my .html both `work` and `dataBasedOncontrols` are subscribed to via the async pipe. The console output is

```
Data Fetched
Building Controls
Building Controls <- This shouldn't happen
Computed Data
```

Shouldn't the `ShareReplay` on the `work` Observable prevent the two tap functions from being executed twice? If I remove the element subscribing to `dataBasedOncontrols` I get the expected behavior. Additionally, when I add a second pipe async element to the work observable I get the duplicated behavior which leads me to believe the `ShareReplay(1)` isn't working properly.

Can someone explain what is going on why `buildControls(data)` in the `work` Observable is being executed twice.

Answer (score 2):

What exact version of `rxjs` are you using?  The behavior changed at version 6.4.0.  I'm going to assume you are using something less than that because your code should work otherwise.

### In versions >= 6.4.0 (and 5.4.0)

There are two things which could cause a resubscription.

1) If the source observable throws an error then that error will be propagated to all current subscribers.  Any future subscription to the shared observable will trigger a resubscription to the source.

2) If `refCount: true` is passed in the configuration when calling `shareReplay` (i.e. `shareReplay({bufferSize: 1, refCount: true})`) AND the source observable has not completed AND there are no current active subscriptions to the shared observable.  Any future subscription will trigger a resubscription to the source.

This could happen pretty easily if, for example, you are using a `first` or `takeUntil` on one of your subscribers.  The first subscriber finishes before the second subscriber subscribes.

### In versions < 6.4.0 (except version 5.4.0):

The rules are pretty much the same except `refCount` does not exist and it is therefore implicitly true.

I suspect this might be your case.  Your first subscriber is finishing before you second subscriber subscribes.  Although it would have to finish before the request finished.  If the request finished then the whole chain would complete and it would lock into place and should never resubscribe.

If you can, then upgrade to >= 6.4.0.  The `refCount` property was added and it defaults to `false` so you don't even have to change your code (although it is nice to be explicit as this is a confusing topic).

This should be safe in your example since the innermost observable is (I suspect) an `http.get` call which should complete when finished.

If your innermost observable doesn't complete then this can be dangerous because your outer observables would never complete either.  This may or may not be a bad thing depending on the situation.

Update: Just to be clear, to use the `refCount` option you have to use the new signature.  The signature is now...

```
export function shareReplay<T>(config: ShareReplayConfig): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T>;
export function shareReplay<T>(bufferSize?: number, windowTime?: number, scheduler?: SchedulerLike): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T>;
```

The second signature is the old one which took parameters directly in the call.  The first signature is the new one which takes a single parameter (a config object).  The config object has `refCount` so you have to switch to the first signature to use it.

Comment: I am using 6.3.3 I updated to 6.5.2 but I'm not seeing the refCount option. Based on your answer I have been able to find out a bit more information. `apiData` has a bit more going on under the hood than just an `http` call and thus only completes when the service that is providing it is taken down, this is intended. The component that is displaying work and it's subsequent compositions is repeatedly taken down and reconstructed, each time this happens it completes but I seem to have a `ghost` subscription and an incrementing number of `building controls` calls.

Comment: If I add a `takeUntil` as the first operator in the `apiData.pipe()` I get my expected behavior. This seems to indicate that even though `work` completes when the component is destroyed, the computations done in the `.pipe()` continue to be executed on subsequent events.

Comment: `refCount` should be present in `6.5.2`.  I've added the signature to my answer to clarify.  You have to call it with a config object instead of the old way (e.g. `shareReplay({bufferSize: 1, refCount: true})` and not `shareReplay(1, true)`).  Since you aren't passing it in then it will do `refCount` false and you would see "ghost" subscriptions.  Without ref counting then `work` will hold on to a subscription to `apiData` forever (or until `apiData` completes).